# Make a main method wait on a smaller method (java)

Tags: java, swing, wait

i really need to find better ways to word my questions.
Basically I've created a program that takes information from a webpage and displays it nicely across the screen.

When the user closes the program, they actually hide it.

I also have another method which constantly loops checking for information to see if tis been updated.
unfortunately the problem im having is that it loops to fast, i only want it to check for information every 40 seconds or so.

What i tried was inserting a wait(1000,1000) in the method itself and in the main of the program. but both of these cause IllegalMonitorStateException.

Is this the correct way to make the thread wait properly? or is there a better way?
note: the only thread i have is the main.

MAIN

```
class Marquee
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setResizable(true);


    while(true)
    {
        // this doesnt work
        frame.wait(1000,1000);
        frame.notifyAll();

        frame.checkForNewUpdate();
        System.out.println("  ____________________________next line _______________________________");

    }
} 
}
```

CHECK FOR UPDATES

```
public String[] checkForNewUpdate()
{
    //setVisible(true);
    String tempUpdate = getEngineersUpdate();

    if (latestUpdate[0] != tempUpdate)
    {
        // do nothign 
        setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(latestUpdate[0]==tempUpdate)
    {
        latestUpdate[0] = tempUpdate;
        //show the page again
        setVisible(true);
    }
    else if(latestUpdate[0]!= "NULL")
    {   
        // do nothing
        //latestUpdate[0] = tempUpdate;
    }
    else
    {
        latestUpdate[0] = tempUpdate;
    }
    return latestUpdate;
}
```

1: WHat am i doing wrong to get this exception

2: Is there any other way to make a gap of time in a method

3: Am i going to have to put all these methods into another thread? Please say no

---

```
// my constructor which I failed to mention has a timer in it. only i dont know hwo to use it

 class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private ActionListener listener;
private Timer t1;
private String [] latestUpdate = new String[1];


public MyFrame()
{
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();// gets the maximum size of the screen 
    setSize(d.width,(d.height/100)*10);//sets it to max. need to change this

    // this shit find the max size of screen and puts it bottom left
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    int x = (int)rect.getMinX();
    int y = (int)rect.getMaxY()-getHeight();
    setLocation(x,y-30);
    setTitle("ALERT::OUTAGE");
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    add(panel);
    listener = this;
    t1 = new Timer(50,listener);
    t1.start();
}
```

by request, here is getEngineersUpdate()

```
public String getEngineersUpdate()  //gets data from page and sets it to string.
{
    String update = "blank";

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);// javascript causes some serious problems.
    webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
    String forChecking;

    HtmlPage page;

    try 
    {

        URL outageURL = new URL("file:\\C:\\Users\\0vertone\\Desktop\\version control\\OUTAGE\\Outages.html"); //local drive at home


        page = webClient.getPage(outageURL);


        //All this crap can be gone if we just give the table an id
        Object[] dates = page.getByXPath("//span[@id='date']/text()").toArray();
        Object[] sites = page.getByXPath("//span[@id='site']/text()").toArray();
        Object[] issues = page.getByXPath("//span[@id='issue']/text()").toArray();
        System.out.println("" + dates[0].toString());
        System.out.println("" + sites[0].toString());
        System.out.println("" + issues[0].toString());

        update = (dates[0].toString() + "   " + sites[0].toString() + "   " +issues[0].toString());
        forChecking = dates[0].toString();




        /**some examples of the getCellAt() method*/
        //update = table.getCellAt(0,0).asText();   // This returns DATE/Time
        //update = table.getCellAt(1,0).asText();   // This return the actual date
        //update = table.getCellAt(0,1).asText();   // This returns, SITE/Sector
        //update = table.getCellAt(1,1).asText();   // This returns the actual site issue

    }
    catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException a) 
    {
    System.out.println("Failing HTTP Status Execution");
    a.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException b) 
    {
    System.out.println("Malformed URL");
    b.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException c) 
    {
    System.out.println("IO PROBLEMS!");
    c.printStackTrace();
    }
webClient.closeAllWindows();
return update;
}
```

Comment: All calls related to the GUI should occur in the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT). Look at SwingUtilities.invokeLater or do a web search for details. Even though you appear to only have one thread the EDT is running as it is started by creating the GUI. You are also using == to compare Strings, use string.equals(otherString) instead.

Comment: you do use swing, so main isn't the only thread you have. There is at least the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code so it should work as you intended. I'm not clear on what getEngineersUpdate() does, so I can't say for sure if it will work, but I've given you a start. I've included 2 options for how to handle it, with explanation in the comments. You can see how to use a Timer properly in the constructor, also. Finally, I don't have your full code, so I had to rig something together to simulate it.

```
class Marquee {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setResizable(true);
    }
}



class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private String [] latestUpdate = new String[1];
    private static final int DISPLAY_TIME = 3000;
    private Timer displayTimer;

    /*
     * Option #1:
     * Ideally, you'd have the thread that generates the "Engineers Update" messages call this
     * method. If you can't make this event based, then you should use option #2
     */
    public void newUpdate(String message) {
        setVisible(true);
        // change this to whatever you need to.
        text.setText(message);
        displayTimer.restart();
    }

    // I used this to test it
    private JTextField text;

    public MyFrame() {
        // gets the maximum size of the screen
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        //sets it to max. need to change this
        setSize(d.width, (d.height / 100) * 10);

        // this shit find the max size of screen and puts it bottom left
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        int x = (int) rect.getMinX();
        int y = (int) rect.getMaxY() - getHeight();
        setLocation(x, y - 30);
        setTitle("ALERT::OUTAGE");

        //MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        //add(panel);
        text = new JTextField("Initial Text");
        add(text);

        // this creates a timer that when it goes off, will hide the frame
        displayTimer = new Timer(DISPLAY_TIME, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        // sets the timer not to repeat
        displayTimer.setRepeats(false);

        //This code is for option #2:
        updateTimer = new Timer(UPDATE_INTERVAL, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                checkForNewUpdate();
            }
        });
        updateTimer.start();
    }

    // This is for option #2
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private Timer updateTimer;

    /*
     * Option #2:
     * Not ideal, but this should work.
     */
    public String[] checkForNewUpdate() {
        // I don't know how getEngineersUpdate() works
        // which would have made it much easier to help you.
        String tempUpdate = getEngineersUpdate();

        // String comparison doesn't work like this in java.
        // you also had a sleeping NullPointerException here
        if (!tempUpdate.equals(latestUpdate[0])) {
            // this is when you have a new update, correct?
            newUpdate(tempUpdate);
            latestUpdate[0] = tempUpdate;
        } else if (tempUpdate.equals(latestUpdate[0])) {
            // it's the same update as last time, so do nothing
        } else if (tempUpdate.equals("NULL")) {
            // You need to handle this according to what getEngineersUpdate() does
        }
        return latestUpdate;
    }

    // This code is rigged to show how it would work
    private static int i = 0;
    private String getEngineersUpdate() {
        // 1 in 6 chance of returning "NULL"
        if (Math.random() * 6 - 1 < 0)
            return "NULL";

        // probability of 1 in 4 of generating a new update
        if(Math.random() * 4 - 1 < 0)
            return "UPDATE #"+i++;
        else
            return "UPDATE #"+i;
    }
}
```

Comment: getEngineersUpdate just returns a string after getting it from a webpage.

Comment: Its actually a bit easier to see whats going on here. Thanks much for that. Im curious as to why you have math.random in there. and I apologize for being such a noob that im not great with event driven stuff. basically: get engineersUpdate returns a string from a http webpage, its a lot of code that would cause confusion. check for updates runs getEngineersupdate and checks it as to whether its been updated recently or not. if it has been updated, then a neat graphic displays across the page with the message.  i created a frame and panel with action listener to do this for me

Comment: Never apologize for a lack of knowledge. The math.random() is in there to create a "random" test for the code. It's important to mention that you can't change your architecture to be event-driven (since you're pulling from a website).

Comment: well It may be workaroundable. This code is great, it may be exactly what i needed. an example of how timer works is great. I feel like im makeing it to complicated for myself. At the moment im trying to figure out how i can display the message on the panel instead of your textfield.            By the way, the text on the website page is always changing. all checkforUpdates was designed to do was check, if the last message i got was different to this one, to redisplay the frame that had been minimized, so in that sense it could be event driven (unless im completely mistaken on what an event is

Comment: ive included the get engineers update message. but it makes no difference i can see to how the program flows. the method i need to wait is still just comparing 2 strings.

Comment: No worries, mate. You should probably add a method to your panel that updates the text (similar to newUpdate(String)). Then call that method from inside MyFrame.newUpdate(String). This could be a useful little widget. I might improve on it in the future...

Comment: it does something similar to that already. see the text is a marquee. it scrolls from right to left using drawstring and it repaints it again and again

Answer (score 0):

1. <strike>I think you can't call wait() on an JFrame, but I am not sure.</strike>
2. You have to call `wait()` within a snychronized-block. (Example below)
3. `Thread.sleep(1000l)` can be used, if it runs in a Thread, but look for the class `Timer`
4. It would be much better design, if you create a thread, which checks for updates. You can notify the GUI (JFrame) with some kind of event-listener about the new date to display.

Take a look at the [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Comment: wait() will work for any object but all calls to wait() must occur in a synchronised block: synchronized (object) { object.wait(); }

Comment: I actually defined a timer in the constructor for MyFrame which i just put in there. But i didnt know how to use it. I still dont.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another thread, you should call checkforNewUpdate method from this thread. And also do not forget use SwingUtilities.invokeLater method to update your UI inside checkforNewUpdate method. here is the some part of the code;

```
 public class Marque         { 

    private JFrame frame;
    class CheckForUpdate implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                checkForNewUpdate();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException(e1);
                }                     }

        }

        public String[] checkForNewUpdate()     { 
            //your code
            // user interface interaction code
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public Marque() {
        frame = new JFrame(); 
        //....frame related code
        new Thread(new CheckForUpdate()).start();


    }  
    public static void main(String[] arg) { 
        Marque marque = new Marque();


    }
```

Comment: trying to combine this with my code is gonna be hard. for some parts i understand what your doing.i have other methods that im trying to work in aswell so i guess ill just have to work around it.